# What's the best way to set custom request headers when using Capybara in RSpec request specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, capybara, request-headers

I'm monkey patching Capybara::Session with a set_headers method that assigns to Capybara::RackTest::Browser's options attribute (which I've changed from an attr_reader to an attr_accessor).

**The patches:**

```
class Capybara::RackTest::Browser
  attr_accessor :options
end

class Capybara::Session
  def set_headers(headers)
    if driver.browser.respond_to?(:options=) #because we've monkey patched it above
      options = driver.browser.options
      if options.nil? || options[:headers].nil?
        options ||= {}
        options[:headers] = headers
      else
        options[:headers].merge!(headers)
      end
    else
      raise Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
    end
  end
end
```

**In my request spec, I'm doing:**

```
page.set_headers("REMOTE_ADDR" => "1.2.3.4")
visit root_path
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way, it seems a bit overkill to just be able to set a custom remote_ip/remote_addr on a request.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the headers to be globally set on all requests, you can use something like:

```
Capybara.register_driver :custom_headers_driver do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new(app, :headers => {'HTTP_FOO' => 'foobar'})
end
```

See the `rack_test_driver_spec.rb` in Capybara 1.1.2 and Capybara's issue #320, [Setting up HTTP headers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/320).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to add custom header into one specific request in rspec using capybara? I used this in acceptance tests. It was the best way for me to use get method with specific header data. You can assess specific element on response page. See my example below:

```
get user_registration_path, { :invite => invite_token }, { 'X_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE' => 'US' } 
expect(assigns(:ip_country)).to eq('US')
response.body.should have_selector("input#currency_usd[checked='checked']")
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered an ability to modify headers when using the default `Capybara::RackTest` driver.

There's a method `Capybara::RackTest::Browser#process` which prepares a request before finaly being sent (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FRackTest%2FBrowser:process). As you can see there in the code the request headers are built from the `options[:headers]`. The `options` actually refers to the `driver.options` attribute. So you can set any headers by modifying this hash.

**Here's an example of my feature spec with custom headers**:

```rb
let(:headers) do
  {
    "YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER_1" => "foo",
    "YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER_2" => "bar",
    ...
  }
end 

before(:each) do
  @origin_headers = page.driver.options[:headers]
  page.driver.options[:headers] ||= {}
  page.driver.options[:headers].merge!(headers)
end

after(:each) do
  page.driver.options[:headers] = @origin_headers
end
```

**Tested with**:

- capybara: 3.13.2 (RackTest driver)
- rspec: 3.8
- rails: 5.2.2

P.S. Haven't tested it with selenium driver yet. But probably it works in a similar way.