# Access to request object in request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I set the request headers before doing the request on a request spec?

I'm moving controller specs to request specs on my API using Rails. One thing I'm stuck on is that I have no access to a `request` object to allow the requests.

On my controller specs, I have access to a method I created which signs a specific user:

```
def sign_in(user)
  token = user.api_keys.first.token
  # note the request object being used in the next line
  request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(token)
end
```

This works fine on controller specs, I can safely do:

```
before { sign_in(user) }
it { post :endpoint, params }
```

But on a request spec, the `request` object is not available. 
If I try to:

```
before { sign_in(user) }
it { post "/api/endpoint", params }
```

I get `request` on my helper method as `nil`.

I know I could do:

```
it { post "/api/endpoint", {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => ... } }
```

But this seems a lot of clutter in the spec, specially compared to a controller spec.

I've tried using `ActionDispatch::TestRequest::DEFAULT_ENV` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12895372/1074361), but it didn't work too (I get a `401`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already using `Rack::Test` for this then you should be. `Rack::Test` is better suited than Capybara for testing API requests. It can be configured in your `rspec/spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

When you're configured to use Rack::Test, you can set headers before the request like so:

```
it 'POST /api/enpoint authenticates successfully' do
  header 'Authorization', '...'
  post "/api/endpoint", params
  expect(last_response).to be_ok
end
```

This will be accessible in your controller as `request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`.

The source code for this method can be found here - https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/master/lib/rack/test.rb#L127-L141

Comment: Is this specified in the rspec documentation anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

If you use capybara for request specs, I guess you can set headers like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062129/whats-the-best-way-to-set-custom-request-headers-when-using-capybara-in-rspec-r), however it's better to perform the real log-in through the HTML form or whatever is the way to authenticate in your app, because request specs are higher level than controller ones, and that's why they normally do not allow you to manually set headers, cookies and other low level stuff.

Comment: This is an API, which only outputs JSON, not something the end user is interacting with.